# My dlink router seems to be compromised

Tags: linux, dns, router, system-compromise

By chance I read today about this huge vulnerability regarding my router Dlink DIR-600. ( http://www.s3cur1ty.de/m1adv2013-003 )
Just out of curiosity about what I would find, I tried to send some commands to it and it also worked on the first attempt. Something like `ls` or `ifconfig` was funny to see from it...  until I tried the `ps` command which printed out the following:

```
PID USER       VSZ STAT COMMAND
    1 0          592 S    init                
    2 0            0 SW   [kthreadd]
    3 0            0 SW   [ksoftirqd/0]
    4 0            0 SW   [events/0]
    5 0            0 SW   [khelper]
    6 0            0 SW   [async/mgr]
    7 0            0 SW   [sync_supers]
    8 0            0 SW   [bdi-default]
    9 0            0 SW   [kblockd/0]
   10 0            0 SW   [cfg80211]
   11 0            0 SW   [rpciod/0]
   12 0            0 SW   [kswapd0]
   13 0            0 SW   [aio/0]
   14 0            0 SW   [nfsiod]
   15 0            0 SW   [crypto/0]
   21 0            0 SW   [mtdblockd]
   60 0         1368 S    xmldb -n wrgn49_dlob_dir600b -t 
   61 0          888 S    servd -d schedule_off 
  177 0          852 S    logd -p notice 
  178 0          828 S    klogd -p notice 
  185 0          852 S    gpiod 
  453 0          996 S    /var/run/fakedns --port=63481 --address=/#/1.33.203.3
  490 0          872 S    ddnsd 
  502 0          832 S    telnetd -l /usr/sbin/login -u Alphanetworks:wrgn49_dl      
  510 0          592 S    init                
  693 0            0 SW   [RtmpCmdQTask]
  700 0         1008 S    hostapd /var/servd/hostapd-ra0.conf 
  701 0          852 S    updatewifistats -i ra0 -x /phyinf:3 -r /runtime/phyin
  723 0          836 S    portt -c DNAT.PORTT 
 1127 0          988 S    udhcpc -i eth2.2 -H dlinkrouter -p /var/servd/WAN-1-u
 1656 0          852 S    neaps -i br0 -c /var/run/neaps.conf 
 1665 0          828 S    netbios -i br0 -r dlinkrouter 
 1666 0          844 S    llmnresp -i br0 -r dlinkrouter 
 1683 0         1012 S    udhcpd /var/servd/LAN-1-udhcpd.conf 
 1769 0          960 S    lld2d -c /var/lld2d.conf br0 ra0 
 1853 0         1008 S    proxyd -m 1.33.203.39 -f /var/run/proxyd.conf -u /var
 1944 0          984 S    dnsmasq -C /var/servd/DNS.conf 
 1973 0         1508 S    httpd -f /var/run/httpd.conf 
 4379 0          968 S    /usr/sbin/phpcgi /htdocs/web/command.php 
 4380 0          692 S    sh -c ps >> /var/cmd.result 
 4381 0          592 R    ps
```

Here I am especially concerned about the telnetserver (pid 502), the fakedns (pid 453) and also the cockiness of my provider, providing a router that is not updated for security vulnerabilities anymore, and taking my money for renting that box to me...
So the first thing to do was to kill all those suspicious processes but, as expected, after a reboot of the machine everything was like before, up and running. I checked several standard config-files but they seemed normal..

So my questions are now: is my router seriously compromised? Is it enough to prevent those processes from starting up? Did I miss something? Also this "xmldb" (pid 60) seems kind of suspicious to me.

Comment: Does your router have a "reset" button to revert to factory resets? This looks completely compromised. You need to get a new router or a new provider.

Comment: @schroeder "completely compromised" how? I am curious

Comment: If after a reboot, the `fakedns` code is still running, it will be impossible to determine how far the intrusion goes. Things are persisting. Time to nuke the thing from orbit.

Comment: @Ulkoma You also have `fakedns` and `proxyd` pointing to the same IP: `1.33.203.3` (Japan)

Comment: yes  that its from japan i figured out too.. but my problem is the providers credentials, i dont know where this letter has gone... 
i would really like to fix this or be able to find the credentials somewhere into the router now that i have root access :S

Comment: +1 to @schroeder for "nuke from orbit" (i.e.: hard reset). Look around some third-party firmware sites for instructions on flashing back to the factory default image. Usually it's something like a "30/30/30" process. If that doesn't clear the badware out, time for a new router. A new ISP wouldn't be a bad idea either. And just never trust the ISP's router in general - put your own behind it.

Comment: @Iszi *put your own behind it*, no, you should rather replace the ISP's garbage with a proper router. Just putting your own router after theirs doesn't change anything to the issue, as the vulnerable router still remains in the network path and can tamper with the traffic if compromised.

Comment: @AndréBorie Some ISPs may not give you that option, or will insist on maintaining their own access to whatever equipment is connected. So, the basic premise boils down to: If you don't *own* the ISP, don't trust the gateway.

Answer (score 2):

When you run ps the output is the current running process list. Sometimes this will list the process including the command line arguments used to start the process. Here are some possibly dangerous looking commands from your output:

```
  453 0          996 S    /var/run/fakedns --port=63481 --address=/#/1.33.203.3
  502 0          832 S    telnetd -l /usr/sbin/login -u Alphanetworks:wrgn49_dl       
 1127 0          988 S    udhcpc -i eth2.2 -H dlinkrouter -p /var/servd/WAN-1-u
 1853 0         1008 S    proxyd -m 1.33.203.39 -f /var/run/proxyd.conf -u /var
 1944 0          984 S    dnsmasq -C /var/servd/DNS.conf 
 4379 0          968 S    /usr/sbin/phpcgi /htdocs/web/command.php 
 4380 0          692 S    sh -c ps >> /var/cmd.result
```

- I see [fakedns](https://github.com/Crypt0s/FakeDns) is pointing all of your dns requests to
  1.33.203.3.
- Telnet accepting connections from only Alphanetworks.
- It appears as if your traffic is being proxied to 1.33.203.39 (can't find any documentation on the -m flag).
- You have a php page running under the name "command.php" I would suggest checking out the source code to that file.
- The output of 'ps' is being appended to cmd.result (that may have been you).

In a possibly related note a google search for "proxyd -m" returns [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kid1412-net/163c787107430be14843).

If any/all of this seems phishy to you, I suggest factory resetting your device. If there are no available patches for your device see if you can load any open source firmwares (such as OpenWRT) and confirm the hash of the image when you download it.

Comment: thanks for the analysis :)
yes that telnet credentials are from a standard passwordlist from backtrack i found out until now.
this "command.php" was also what granted me today the access to the routers cli

This proxyd is seems pretty tough to me... i kill the process - it starts again...
there is also a dynamic dns running as far as i can see, ddnsd. Maybe here i can find out something about where this goes?

Comment: so unfortunately for my hardware version of this shi*** dlink router, there is no wrt image available :-(
the reset with the reset button did nothing, everything is still there..

Comment: How out of date is this thing? You don't need WRT or any other open source stuff, just the latest factory firmware if it has been patched and reload it. The reset button merely clears the configuration memory, so whatever's been flashed is still there. If properly patched firmware isn't available for reload, smash it with a hammer and send it out in the first garbage pickup so someone else doesn't get bitten.

Comment: Ok tonight, after work, i will try to flash the factories firmware. I will let you know about the results

Comment: The outcome is, that i found a newer firmware but i cannot telnet into the router anymore to check if those backdoors are really gone now...
Does someone has an idea how to verify the removal of that stuff?
I guess the initial entry point for all of this, command.php is fixed now, posts to this file seem not to do anything anymore

Comment: @fab you can try using traceroute to see if you're passing through the proxy